# Angularjs + Sharepoint 2013: Adding elements to a list

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint

I'm making code snipet to Sharepoint so users can use it without visual studio. I'm trying to add items into Sharepoint 2013 list using Angularjs input fields. I have successfully been able to get items from the list and the Customer list shows correctly so I know the Angular is working but writing is more difficult and does not seem to work. Here is my solution by far:

**Script**

```js
var App = angular.module('list-module', []);


App.controller('list-controller', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Customers')/items?$select=Title,order0",

        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.customers = data.d.results;

    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        alert("error");
    });

    $scope.addItem = function () {
        $scope.items.push($scope.newItem);
    };

    $scope.item = { order0: "" };
    $scope.addItem = function ($event) {
        var x = $scope.item;
        $event.preventDefault();
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = clientContext.get_web();
        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Customers');
        var listItemInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        var listItem = list.addItem(listItemInfo);
        listItem.set_item('Title', x.Title);
        listItem.set_item('order0', x.order0);
        listItem.update();

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded),
            Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed)
            );
    };
    onQuerySucceeded = function () {
        alert('Item Added Successfully');
    }

    onQueryFailed = function (sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }

}
);

angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['list-module']);
});
```

**HTML**

```html
<div ng-app="list-module"></div>
<div ng-controller='list-controller'>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10">

                </br>
                </br>
                Search:
                <input ng-model="query">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                </br>
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Order</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers | filter:query">
                        <td>{{customer.Title}}</td>
                        <td>{{customer.order0}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="TitelInput">Title</label>
                    <input style="width: 200px;" type="text" class="form-control" id="TitelInput" data-ng-model="item.Title">

                    <label for="OrderInput">Order</label>
                    <input style="width: 200px;" type="text" class="form-control" id="OrderInput" data-ng-model="item.order0">


                    <button style="width: 100px;" ng-click="addItem(($event)" class="btn btn-primary">Add Item</button>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="/SiteAssets/CSS/tableStyle_simple.css">
<script src="/SiteAssets/javascript/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js">
</script>

<script src="/SiteAssets/javascript/listController2.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

I'm wondering why the list won't take the new values.

Hopefully someone can help.

Comment: What list? I see no list bound to scope besides customers.

Comment: I'm trying to add to that same customers list.

Comment: You have two `$scope.addItem` functions.